# Making ServiceStack RedisSentinel use a RedisManagerPool instead of a PooledRedisClientManager

Tags: servicestack, servicestack.redis

Using ServiceStack version 4.0.40.

I am trying get RedisSentinel to use the RedisManagerPool instead of the 
PooledRedisClientManager so it will allow clients above the client pool size.

I see this in the docs to set this...

```
sentinel.RedisManagerFactory = (master,slaves) => new RedisManagerPool(master);
```

I'm not sure how to use this. Do I pass in the master host name? What if I don't know which is master because of a previous failover? I can't sentinel.start() to find out which is master because it will start with the PooledRedisClientManager, which isn't what I want.

Or, do I pass in the sentinel hosts? RedisManagerPool takes a list of hosts, I can pass in the sentinel hosts, but I cannot set it to sentinel.RedisManagerFactory as RedisManagerFactory is not convertible to RedisManagerPool.

I think I am missing something simple here. Any help appreciated.

**UPDATE**

As per mythz's comment below, this isn't available in version 4.0.40 of ServiceStack. But you can use;

```
  sential.RedisManagerFactory.FactoryFn = (master, slaves) => new RedisManagerPool(master);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is literally the config you need to use to change RedisSentinel to use RedisManagerPool:

```
sentinel.RedisManagerFactory = (master,slaves) => 
    new RedisManagerPool(master);
```

You don’t need to pass anything else, the master host argument uses the lambda argument.

Comment: I get the error 'Cannot convert lamda expression of type 'RedisManagerFactory' because it is not a delegate type'

Comment: @Dan then your version is too old and doesn’t support it.

Comment: At which version did you start supporting it? Is there another way of setting the max client pool size in version 4.0.40?

Comment: @Dan I don’t recall and looks like you can use `RedisManagerFactory.FactoryFn = (master,slaves) => new  RedisManagerPool(master);` in v4.0.40.